# How can I join two hashes in Perl without using a loop?

Tags: perl, hash

How do I append hash a to hash b in Perl without using a loop?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you mean take the union of their data, just do:

```
%c = (%a, %b);
```

Comment: It works for me: "%a=('a' => 'b', 'c' => 1); %b=('c' => 'd'); %a = (%a, %b); print join(', ', map { "'$_' => \"${a{$_}}\"" } keys %a), "\n";" Items from %b with the same key take precedence, but other items from %a are present after the union.

Comment: that might be the OP's problem, they might want to merge the values of the hash, so $a{'c'} ends up being [1, 'd']

Comment: In which case they should look at Hash::Merge on the CPAN

Answer (score 24):

You can also use slices to merge one hash into another:

```
@a{keys %b} = values %b;
```

Note that items in %b will overwrite items in %a that have the same key.

Comment: For extra credit, with a hash ref in a and b, we do @{$a}{keys %$b} = values %$b;

Comment: I expect this to be more efficient than the other reply, because that one recreates the hash also for the already existing items, while this one just adds keys for the new items. If there were many items in %a, compared to %b, the difference can be respectable.

Comment: Maybe. My approach also walks %b twice. If %b is larger than %a, the other technique might be faster. Fastest of all might be a loop, but the OP didn't want that.

Comment: @bart: looks like you were right. Some rather simple timing tests for perl 5.8.9 on OS X 10.4 place the slice approach about 2.4 times faster, even with %b much larger than %a. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: This should also work for blessed hashrefs if I'm not severely mistaken. Trying it out now. Handy!

Answer (score 2):

This will merge hashes and also take into account undefined entries, so they don't replace the content.

```
my %hash = merge(\%hash1, \%hash2, \%hash3);

sub merge {
    my %result;

    %result = %{ $_[0] };
    shift;

    foreach my $ref (@_) {
        for my $key ( keys %{$ref} ) {
            if ( defined $ref->{$key} ) {
                $result{$key} = $ref->{$key};
            }
        }
    }

    return %result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my %c = %a;
map {$c{$_} = $b{$_}} keys %b;
```